# WSO2 ESB message processor fails sending messages to rabbitMQ endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

In WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 I configured a Scheduled Message Forwarding Processor to forward messages to a rabbitMQ message queue.

If I configure the targetEndpoint parameter in the message processor pointing to a proxy or API within the ESB, and then I send it to the rabbitMQ message queue, it works and no errors.

However, I would like the targetEndpoint to simply point directly to the external rabbitMQ message queue, with no proxy or API workaround.

For this, I create an endpoint whose address url is basically this (no properties nor parameters):

```
rabbitmq:/AMQPProxy?rabbitmq.confirm.delivery=true&amp;rabbitmq.connection.pool.size=10&amp;rabbitmq.server.host.name=localhost&amp;rabbitmq.server.port=5672&amp;rabbitmq.server.user.name=guest&amp;rabbitmq.server.password=guest&amp;rabbitmq.queue.name=MyQueue&amp;rabbitmq.queue.routing.key=MyQueue
```

Then I point the targetEndpoint parameter in the message processor to this endpoint, and I get the following error.

```
[2017-05-08 16:49:12,298] ERROR - ForwardingService BlockingMessageSender of message processor [rabbitmq-message-processor] failed to send message to the endpoint
[2017-05-08 16:49:17,299] ERROR - ClientUtils The system cannot infer the transport information from the rabbitmq:/AMQPProxy?rabbitmq.confirm.delivery=true&amp;rabbitmq.connection.pool.size=10&amp;rabbitmq.server.host.name=localhost&amp;rabbitmq.server.port=5672&amp;rabbitmq.server.user.name=guest&amp;rabbitmq.server.password=guest&amp;rabbitmq.queue.name=MyQueue&amp;rabbitmq.queue.routing.key=MyQueue URL.
[2017-05-08 16:49:17,299] ERROR - BlockingMsgSender Error sending Message to url : rabbitmq:/AMQPProxy?rabbitmq.confirm.delivery=true&amp;rabbitmq.connection.pool.size=10&amp;rabbitmq.server.host.name=localhost&amp;rabbitmq.server.port=5672&amp;rabbitmq.server.user.name=guest&amp;rabbitmq.server.password=guest&amp;rabbitmq.queue.name=MyQueue&amp;rabbitmq.queue.routing.key=MyQueue
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information from the rabbitmq:/AMQPProxy?rabbitmq.confirm.delivery=true&amp;rabbitmq.connection.pool.size=10&amp;rabbitmq.server.host.name=localhost&amp;rabbitmq.server.port=5672&amp;rabbitmq.server.user.name=guest&amp;rabbitmq.server.password=guest&amp;rabbitmq.queue.name=MyQueue&amp;rabbitmq.queue.routing.key=MyQueue URL.
    at org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils.inferOutTransport(ClientUtils.java:81)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.prepareMessageContext(OperationClient.java:288)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutOnlyAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutOnlyAxisOperation.java:249)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.sendRobust(BlockingMsgSender.java:265)
    at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.send(BlockingMsgSender.java:183)
    at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ForwardingService.dispatch(ForwardingService.java:465)
    at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ForwardingService.execute(ForwardingService.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.ntask.NTaskAdapter.execute(NTaskAdapter.java:90)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:67)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-05-08 16:49:17,301] ERROR - ForwardingService BlockingMessageSender of message processor [rabbitmq-message-processor] failed to send message to the endpoint
```

Could you tell me if it is possible to solve it and how?

Comment: In generall this should work (e.g. https://kishanthan.wordpress.com/2013/03/26/amqp-transport-for-wso2-esb-based-on-rabbitmq-java-client/). I assume you have configured the transportSender and transportReceiver. The onyl difference I see is that you are missing rabbitmq.exchange.name and rabbitmq.connection.factory=CachedRabbitMQConnectionFactory. Because we are using ActiveMQ I am not sure if that helps. In ActiveMQ you have to pass connection factory in the url (e.g. ?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;).

Comment: Thank you but it is not working. I can succesfully send messages to the same endpoint from a proxy or API. The problem is that the message processor seems unable to infer the rabbitmq transport from the endpoint in the targetEndpoint property. I have to use this workaround of forwarding it first to a proxy in the ESB.